# GUI Panel ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, validation, jpanel, jbutton

I have a game application where I need to input a file and after the file is parsed, I can click on a button Start and the game (positioned in the Center panel) starts. I have a top panel (fileBrowserPanel where I browse the filesystem for the file) and that panel has Browse, Start buttons. When I click on Start, the game should start running. Here is my code:

```
public BallWorld() 
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //File browser for INI file
        JPanel fileBrowserPanel = new fileBrowserPanel();
        add(fileBrowserPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        fileBrowserPanel.add(jbtStart);

        //Ball container
        if(filePathField.getText().equals(" "))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input the XML file","Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);        
        }

        jbtStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(filePathField.getText().equals(" "))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input the XML file","Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);        
            }

            else
            {
                JPanel ballContainer = new BallContainer(filePathField.getText());
                add(ballContainer,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }

        }
        });


    }
```

The problem is that it is only when I resize the window that the game in the center panel shows up. I can't quite figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

call validate() at the end of the constructor

Comment: Hey thanks, that did the trick! Can you explain the validate() function please?Thanks~

Comment: as far as I know it is like a refresh to a webpage. it forces the panel to layout itself and its subcomponents again